# Keras model doesn't update weights

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to make a simple neural network with Keras, but my weights won't update after calling fit()

To test the model, I created a simple data set, called mem. mem is a deque of tuples. mem[i][0] gives a np.array of size inp_len of only ones or only zeros.

Here is my code:

```
inp_len = 5*3 + 3187*4
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=124, kernel_initializer='ones', input_shape = (inp_len,)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
model.add(Dense(48, kernel_initializer='ones'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
model.add(Dense(48, kernel_initializer='ones'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
model.add(Dense(48, kernel_initializer='ones'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate, decay=learning_rate_decay))

batch_size = 20
batch_old = random.sample(mem, min(len(mem), batch_size))
for i_batch in range(len(batch_old)):
    X = batch_old[i_batch][0].reshape(1,inp_len)
    y = np.array([[X[0]]])
    model.fit(X, y, epochs = 1, batch_size = 1)
```

I use 1 epoch and with a batch size of 1, because I want to use `model.predict()` in another part of the code with a different batch size.

Can someone please explain why `model.get_weights()[0]` keeps returning ones after fitting the model?

Comment: can you explain the `for` loop?,also just one epochs of training,I don't think you are doing it right

Comment: I  changed the `for` loop, hope it's more clear now. `X` is just an np.array of ones or zeros. `y` is one or zero. Since the batch size will be variable when using `model.predict()` in another part of the code, I want to use one epoch with batch size of 1 when fitting the model. Unless there is another way to solve it.

Comment: What are your learning_rate and learning_rate_decay?

Comment: and also, what do you mean by: " I want to use model.predict() in another part of the code with a different batch size."?